# PHP - Certain GET Usage

Tags: php, arrays, get

So I have my links set like:

```
https://hidden.io/buy?minecraft&pc
```

Tried:

```
$_GET[0], $_GET[1]
var_dump() showed me that GET doesn't function like that.
```

Website example using this way of GET already:

```
https://namemc.com/s?ChloeKitty
(S is a Directory)
```

Im not looking for stuff like:

```
https://hidden.io/buy?game=minecraft&platform=pc
```

How could I make it so I can make a usable array like:

```
$array[0] // "minecraft"
$array[1] // "pc"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
print_r( array_keys( $_GET ) );
$vars=array_keys( $_GET );
echo $vars[0]; /*etc*/
```

Comment: Perfect, Please add this to your answer: `$x= array_keys($_GET);
echo $x[1];`

Comment: it already is posted as an answer :) btw - in your html ( on our site ) there is no closing `img` tag ~ ie: `</img>` is not valid!

Answer (score 1):

Try it like:

```
$myArray = explode('&', $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]);
```

Comment: Yes I know that is how GET works but I dont prefer to have Game and PlayOn attributes.

Comment: Also please remove my website url from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the PHP built-in function to parse query string [parse_str()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
parse_str($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"], $output);
array_keys($output);
```